# How to set right BackGroundImage in C#?

Tags: c#, background-image

I have a problem, I am trying to put some BackGroundImage in my Form Splash Screen, but It's not working.

**What happens is that I try to put the Image in my Form, and It's appears  a lot of the same equal image.**

Here are the image of the problem : **https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRX9n.png**

[image]

**How can I fix that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [BackgroundImageLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on your control.  You want to set it to something other than `ImageLayout.Tile`.

Comment: @Pete, yes, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to your **BackgroundImageLayout** property. It's set as "Tile". Change it to "Stretch", or even "Center".

[image]